# Django Tutorial 1: cannot fix error "File "<console>", line 1, in <module>ImportError: cannot import name Choice"

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am working through the Django tutorial found at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial01/.

I have made it through the initial setup and am at the section "Playing with the API"... when I enter the first line of code to the shell

```
from polls.models import Poll, Choice
```

I get the error

```
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name Choice
```

Choice is a model I have created in the polls app

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField()
```

Please help me understand how to fix my app to allow me to import Choice, and understand the model, shell, import structure better.

UPDATE:
Here is the code to my settings.py file, hopefully it is helpful. The main changes made in the tutorial were adding the `'polls'` app to the `INSTALLED_APPS` and setting a path for the database.

```
# Django settings for mysite project.

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Arye Barnehama', 'arye@axioinc.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': '/Users/azbpolo/projects/sqlite3.db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = '$^_7&amp;hpi5q2%8a6u9=ik$n0-27i9tydxsa9w_7q)90jym+y11h'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'polls'
    #'django.contrib.messages',
    #'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: So: you have the app directory `polls`, and the file `models.py` inside it? This sort of problem is often difficult to pinpoint without seeing the entire picture.

Comment: Can you even import the Poll class?

Comment: So I gues the previous steps in the tutorial worked ok? Are you sure you run `python manage.py shell` in the `mysite` directory? You need to be more specific. There's no single answer with the input you gave us.

Comment: Did you try with
`from polls.models import *`

Maybe, you have an typographical error

Comment: @limelights I can import the Poll class if I leave out Choice.

Comment: I have posted the code from my `setting.py` file above.

Comment: @DaveK. I am running `python manage.py shell` in the `mysite` directory, and i am fairly sure it is the right one, as it only recognizes the `manage.py` file if i'm in this directory.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan I have the 'project' directory which holds ('mysite', 'sql3.db', and 'skeleton'). 'mysite' then holds another file named 'mysite' as well as the app directory 'polls' which has the 'models.py' inside it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your file structure is wrong. It should be:

```
--mysite
 |--manage.py
 |--polls
   |--models.py
 |--mysite
   |--settings.py
   |--urls.py
```

Instead do you have this?

```
--mysite
 |--manage.py
 |--mysite
   |--polls
     |--models.py
   |--settings.py
   |--urls.py
```

If the file structure was correct, and there was something else wrong, then the error code would be something like this

```
>>> from polls.models import Poll, Choice
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "polls/models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    if DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS not in settings.DATABASES:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 184, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
    raise ImportError("Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable %s is undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

Comment: Correct, my file structure was wrong. Thanks you! - problem solved

Comment: @user1943786 You could actually leave the polls directory where it is, and then you would just type `import mysite.polls.models` instead of `import polls.models`. And since this solved your problem, could you mark this as the correct answer? thanks :)